# How to set Ralink RT5390 into N mode using iw?

Tags: linux, wifi

I'm working on supporting a new wifi card for my company. This is the first `n` mode card I've worked with, previously we've used `iw` to set the cards into either `b` or `g` mode as follows:

```
case $mode in
  1) iw dev $name set bitrates legacy-2.4 1 2 5.5 11;; # 802.11b
  2) iw dev $name set bitrates legacy-2.4 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54;; # 802.11g only
esac
```

I'm looking for a third command for the `case` statement, but I've not been able to find anything on google.